# how to format a code which is in string to java format

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a wizard page. In that page i am converting a file into String and displaying it in the text box

But I want to display the text in a java format
I have tried with the below code

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ToolFactory;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.CodeFormatter;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.BadLocationException;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.Document;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.text.edits.MalformedTreeException;
import org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEdit;
    public class FormatterTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String code = pagehandlerContent; //the file which im getting and saving it in string
            CodeFormatter codeFormatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(null);
            TextEdit textEdit = codeFormatter.format(CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT, code, 0, code.length(), 0, null);
            IDocument doc = new Document(code);
            try {
                textEdit.apply(doc);
                System.out.println(doc.get());
            } catch (MalformedTreeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

but I am getting null pointer exception at textEdit.apply(doc) line

Comment: Am I missing something or does `pagehandlerContent` just appear out of nowhere?

Comment: Nice. Asking about formatting a String according to Java source code format rules, but not formatting the example code at all. :-)

Comment: pagehandlercontent is the string in which im getting the file  handlename= "c:\...."//file path                              Utilities utilities = new utililties(); //URLCLASSLOADER for java project class path entries  pagehandlercontent=utilities.readFromFile(handlername);

Answer (score 0):

Your CodeFormatter is null

`CodeFormatter codeFormatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(null);`

Note: I Cant write comment

Comment: what should i write instead of null?

Comment: I cant trying your code at my workspace. I think your problem at this code